# android request json data:content has been consumed

Tags: android, json, httpresponse

this is my html code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $.getJSON("/tasks.json", function(data){
            $.each(data, function(index, d){
                alert(d.alias);
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

it's work...

and this is my android code

```
 HttpEntity entity = null;
        HttpEntity temp = response.getEntity();
        if(temp != null) {
            entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(temp);
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(temp, HTTP.UTF_8);
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
```

Sometimes, `EntityUtils.toString(temp, HTTP.UTF_8)` returns an empty string.
Mostly, I got an exception like `IllegalStateException:content has been consumed`

please help...

/*****************CODE1*******************/

```
@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="{alias}/{status}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Push> getShopInJSON(@PathVariable String alias,@PathVariable String status) {
        List<Push> results ="uncompleted".equalsIgnoreCase(status) ? pushService.findAllUncompleted(alias) :
                "all".equalsIgnoreCase(status) ? pushService.findByAlias(alias) : new ArrayList<Push>();
        return results;
    }
```

this time i use spring Controller,it's works for my android app json request..

but this..
/*****************CODE2*******************/

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="com.easy.push.data.Push" %>
<%@ page import="com.easy.push.service.PushService" %>
<%@ page import="java.util.ArrayList" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.IOException" %>
<%!    
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    private PushService pushService;
    private String status="uncompleted";
    private String alias="15072203031";
    Object execute() throws IOException {
        List<Push> results ="uncompleted".equalsIgnoreCase(status) ? pushService.findAllUncompleted(alias) :
                "all".equalsIgnoreCase(status) ? pushService.findByAlias(alias) : new ArrayList<Push>();
        response.getWriter().write(gson.toJson(results));
        return results;
    }
%>
```

it's work for my webapp,but android app not work..

CODE1 good for webapp,android

CODE2 good for webapp

why CODE2 not working on my android code

tks everyone..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way**
***Create this Method***

```
public String getResponseBody(final HttpEntity entity) throws IOException, ParseException {


        if (entity == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("HTTP entity may not be null");
        }

        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();

        if (instream == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (entity.getContentLength() > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(

            "HTTP entity too large to be buffered in memory");
        }


        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, HTTP.UTF_8));

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

        } finally {
            instream.close();
            reader.close();
        }

        return buffer.toString();

    }
```

**In your code**

```
HttpEntity entity = null;
        HttpEntity temp = response.getEntity();
        if(temp != null) {
            entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(temp);
            responseBody = getResponseBody(temp);
            System.out.println(responseBody);
        }
```

Comment: tks ,i trying coded like it,but it's not work,
reader.readerLine() is null.i have no idea 
anyway..thanks again..